# Is there an option to remove <properties> and <system-out> data on the maven surefire:test xml report

Tags: maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

Is there an option to remove  and  data on the maven surefire:test xml report

the xml file exported contains data that makes the file large, including  data that is not needed for us.

Is there a was to disable this?

Comment: I'm looking for this too, although my reason is that I want to avoid the `\uffff` character in the `<system-out>` part of the XML since TeamCity can't parse it.

Comment: Did any one get resolution to this issue?